# Wildcarded search not working as expected using MarkLogic Java API vs QConsole

Tags: xquery, wildcard, marklogic

Trying to write a query which would return Tesla Modal 3's purchased on 2019-12-10 (ignoring timestamp) but, getting different results when running wildcard searches in QConsole vs Java Api. FYI, enabled trailing wildcard searches and trailing wildcard word positions indexes.

Given the below data.

```
[
  {
    "com.dealership.luckyAuto.carTransactions": {
      "carName": "Tesla",
      "carModal": "3",
      "buyer": "Bob",
      "purchasedDate": "2017-04-26T22:00:00.000Z"
    }
  },
  {
    "com.dealership.luckyAuto.carTransactions": {
      "carName": "Tesla",
      "carModal": "X",
      "buyer": "Ted",
      "purchasedDate": "2015-04-26T03:00:00.000Z"
    }
  },
  {
    "com.dealership.luckyAuto.carTransactions": {
      "carName": "Tesla",
      "carModal": "Y",
      "buyer": "Carol",
      "purchasedDate": "2016-04-26T10:00:00.000Z"
    }
  },
  {
    "com.dealership.luckyAuto.carTransactions": {
      "carName": "Audi",
      "carModal": "Q3",
      "buyer": "Alice",
      "purchasedDate": "2015-04-26T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
  },
  {
    "com.dealership.luckyAuto.carTransactions": {
      "carName": "Audi",
      "carModal": "Q4",
      "buyer": "Lori",
      "purchasedDate": "2016-04-26T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
  },
  {
    "com.dealership.luckyAuto.carTransactions": {
      "carName": "Audi",
      "carModal": "Q5",
      "buyer": "Alax",
      "purchasedDate": "2018-04-26T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
  }
]
```

When below query is executed in QConsole, **result is 0**. (Expected)

```
cts.search(
    cts.andQuery([
    cts.collectionQuery("com.dealership.luckyAuto.carTransactions"),
    cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("carName", "Tesla"),
          cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("carModal", "3"),
          cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("purchasedDate", "2019-12-10T*", ("wildcarded"))
    ]
    ) 
)
```

But when below struturedQuery is executed, the result is (Matching only on carName and carModal. Wildcarded purchasedDate field is ignored)

```
Tesla   3   Bob     2015-03-23T00:00:00.000+0000
Tesla   3   Jeff    2017-03-21T00:00:00.000+0000
```

StruturedQuery:

```
StructuredQueryBuilder().run {
and(
    value(jsonProperty("carName"), "Tesla"),
    value(jsonProperty("carModal"), "3"),
    value(
            jsonProperty("purchasedDate"),
            StructuredQueryBuilder.FragmentScope.DOCUMENTS,
            arrayOf("wildcarded"),
            1.0,
            "2019-12-10T*"
        )
    )}
```

Serialize Query:

```
<query xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <and-query>
        <value-query type="string">
            <json-property>carName</json-property>
            <text>Tesla</text>
        </value-query>
        <value-query type="string">
            <json-property>carModal</json-property>
            <text>3</text>
        </value-query>
        <value-query type="string">
            <json-property>purchasedDate</json-property>
            <fragment-scope>documents</fragment-scope>
            <text>2019-12-10T*</text>
            <term-option>wildcarded</term-option>
            <weight>1.0</weight>
        </value-query>
    </and-query>
</query>
```

Comment: Perhaps because the cts:search is filtered by default and the Java isn’t, so the search eliminates the false positive while Java doesn’t. Try making the search “unfiltered” and you’ll probably get the same results as Java. The right solution then will be to make the query and indexes match up so filtering isn’t required for accuracy.

Comment: Please provide sample documents so that we can have some more insight.

Comment: @DavidEnnis Converted the image to document in questions.

Comment: Footnoting Mr Hunter's suggestion, does the database have the appropriate indexes to support unfiltered wildcards?  See  http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/wildcard#id_14163

Comment: @ehennum I have viewed that document. Enabled trailing wildcard searches and trailing wildcard word indexes, but still not helpful.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion in making the cts:search unfiltered and seeing if its results then match the Java? If they do, then we know the root issue and you can focus on making the query and index work together to not need filtering.

Comment: Your last value-query has multiple tokens (separated by dash). You might need to enable positions to enable MarkLogic to resolve it from indexes. I'd follow hunterhackers advice, and confirm filtering is the root cause. After that, either work in index settings, or just consider putting a range index on it, and doing a range-query on a date range..